# What am I supposed to do with users like this?

Tags: discussion, questions, users

So this Girl/Bot is posting the same question every few hours and sometimes she deletes the old question sometimes it stays. The question itself is not hard, its common mistake but I don't get why she never comments on the provided answers and just reuplods the question. Now she has posted the same question 5 times in 24h.

My biggest concern is that she is getting upvotes for her Questions. Not just one but multiple up votes. Me and others keep down voting her but it does not help. Is there any way to see who upvoted? I would like to ask that person whats up.

Comment: None of the questions on that account are deleted.

Comment: I think I saw her asking the question another time and suddenly it disappeared so I thought it probably was deleted....

Comment: You should dupe-vote/flag the newer questions as a dupe of the oldest one. You can also mod-flag one of the dupes and explain this suspcious behaviour.

Comment: By the look of the downvotes on her questions, seem like she's on the highway to question ban land

Comment: In future, please flag the account for moderator attention; using the meta mob is a little over the top here. Flag the posts as duplicates or off-topic as needed. I'll deal with the posts and the account from here.

Comment: Yeah I marked it as duplicate one time, Next time I will directly call the mod. You guys did not went easy on this account. She won't be able to ask a question so soon...

Comment: That's what you get when you call for the nuclear option.

Comment: @rickastley Hahahah "the nuclear Option". Never laughed so hard on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There were 3 repetitions of the same question here; the previous questions were about different details and issues.

Yes, the account should not be re-posting the same question over and over again. For a first duplicate post, just flag / vote to close the question as a duplicate of the first post (for posts by the same author you can do so even if there are no upvoted answers on the dupe target).

For a case like this, where the account keeps re-posting the same question, you can use a custom flag to ask for moderator attention. We can have a private word with the account pointing them to resources on how to improve the existing question.